# Arranging 3 red balls, 2 blue balls, and 2 green balls so that no two adjacent balls are of the same color

Tags: r

I want to arrange 3 red balls, 2 blue balls, and 2 green balls in a line so that no two balls of the same color are adjacent. If there are no such restrictions, then the number of such unique arrangements is

[image].

Below is the code in R that I used to solve this problem. The idea is to get all 210 unique arrangement, then count the cases where two adjacent cells in a row are of the same color. With this algorithm, I get 38 as the answer. I feel that my code is such an ugly hack. How would you do this in R (or your preferred language)?

```
colors <- c("R", "R", "R", "B", "B", "G", "G")
n <- 1:10000
x <- matrix(rep(NA, times=70000), ncol=7)
for (i in n) x[i,] <- sample(colors)
x <- unique(x)
rows <- nrow(x)
y <- rep(NA, times =rows)
for (i in 1:rows) {
  y[i] <- x[i,1]==x[i,2] | 
    x[i,2]==x[i,3] | 
    x[i,3]==x[i,4] | 
    x[i,4]==x[i,5] | 
    x[i,5]==x[i,6] | 
    x[i,6] == x[i,7]
  }
table(y)
## y
## FALSE  TRUE 
##    38   172
```

Comment: Just to help people that will be looking for permutation functions in the future. The only ones I know and can work with character vectors with duplicate values are: `Permn` as suggested by @timfaber (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.19/topics/Permn) and `perm` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Deducer/versions/0.7-9/topics/perm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you the same values in an easier format:

```
library(DescTools)
library(Hmisc)

out = Permn(colors)
table(apply(out,1,function(x) any(x==Lag(x))))
```

Comment: Is `Lag` from a package?

Comment: Thank you for showing me `DescTools`. However, shouldn't `Lag` be `lag`? But if I use `lag`, all rows will result to `TRUE`.

Comment: Also, `table(apply(out,1,function(x) any(x==lag(x)==T)))` gives an error, which disappears when I remove `==T`.

Comment: added the additional library dependencies. The error might be due to the last bracket, the code seems to work for me.

Comment: the `Lag` function comes from Hmsic and is not the same as `lag`. The latter produces NA by shifting the position while Lag produces empty values which works better here.

Comment: I figured by typing `??Lag` that you were using `Hmisc`. The code works if I put parentheses around `x==Lag(x)`. But `table(apply(out,1,function(x) any(x==Lag(x))))` just as fine.

Comment: Ah of course, the function returns T/F anyways so no check (==T) is necessary, good one, updated the function :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @timfaber is great. I'll add a bit more complex answer that enables you to get some more info out of the process. It will tell you how the color series (permutation) looks like and how many times you have adjacent colors:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DescTools)

# vector of colors
colors <- c("R", "R", "R", "B", "B", "G", "G")

Permn(colors) %>%                    # permute colors
  tbl_df() %>%                       # save it as dataframe
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%      # create permutation id
  gather(v, color, -id) %>%          # reshape data
  select(-v) %>%                     # remove unecessary column
  group_by(id) %>%                   # for each permutation id
  mutate(color_series = paste0(color, collapse = "_"),                       # create the series of colors
         color_lag = lag(color),                                             # get the previous color
         IsSameColor = if_else(color == color_lag, 1, 0, missing = 0)) %>%   # check if you have adjacent colors
  group_by(id, color_series) %>%                                             # for each permutation id and color series
  summarise(CountSameColor = sum(IsSameColor)) %>%                           # count number of adjacent colors
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 210 x 3
#      id  color_series CountSameColor
#   <int>         <chr>          <dbl>
# 1     1 R_R_R_B_B_G_G              4
# 2     2 R_R_B_R_B_G_G              2
# 3     3 R_B_R_R_B_G_G              2
# 4     4 B_R_R_R_B_G_G              3
# 5     5 R_R_B_B_R_G_G              3
# 6     6 R_B_R_B_R_G_G              1
# 7     7 B_R_R_B_R_G_G              2
# 8     8 R_B_B_R_R_G_G              3
# 9     9 B_R_B_R_R_G_G              2
# 10    10 B_B_R_R_R_G_G             4
# # ... with 200 more rows
```

If you want only cases (permutations) with now adjacent colors add a filter `filter(CountSameColor == 0)` in the end.

Comment: This is very useful indeed as it gives an insight on the distribution of the number of times that each pair of adjacent cells in a row have the same color. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could as well use run length encoding:

```
library(DescTools)
# 3 red balls, 2 blue balls, and 2 green
m <- Permn(rep(c("R","B","G"), times=c(3,2,2)))

# use run length encoding to find adjacent elements
table(apply(m, 1, function(x) 
            (length(rle(x)$lengths)!=7)))
```